# Date in XLS sheet not parsing correctly

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I am trying to read a XLS file using 'XLSX' node-module with a column having dates. After parsing the file what I found is that the dates are of few dates back from that of the dates in the sheet.
This is what I a doing.

```html
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath);
var grossPayoutSheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheets[1]];
for (var i in grossPayoutSheet) {
    if (i[0] === "!") continue;
    var col = (!isNaN(parseInt(i.substring(1)))) ? i.substring(0,1) : i.substring(0,2);
    var row = (!isNaN(parseInt(i.substring(1)))) ? parseInt(i.substring(1)) : parseInt(i.substring(2));
    var value = grossPayoutSheet[i].v;
    if (row === 2) {
     var value = grossPayoutSheet[i].v;
     headers[col] = value.trim();
     continue;
    }
    if (row !== 1 && !data[row]) {
     data[row] = {};
    } else if (row !== 1){
     data[row][headers[col]] = value;
    }
   }
```

the value in the cell B3 is

> 05/07/2017

but after parsing the value is

> B3: { t: 'n', v: 42921, w: '42921' }

I want the date in string format that is I want to change the cell format from 'n' to 's'

Can anyone please me out with this?

Comment: Did you get this working? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I got it working yesterday:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'
import * as df from 'dateformat';
// Typescript but easy to convert
const workbook: any = XLSX.read(source, { 'type': type, cellDates: true });
// passing the option 'cellDates': true is important
// ...
// ... until you start reading cells
const cellAddress: any = { c: 5, r: 5 }; // column 5 / row 5 which is a date and formatted like that in xlsx
const cell_ref: string = XLSX.utils.encode_cell(cellAddress);
const cell: any = worksheet[cell_ref];
if (cell) {
    let value: any = cell.v;
    const parsedDate: Date = new Date(value);
    parsedDate.setHours(parsedDate.getHours() + timezoneOffset); // utc-dates
    value = df(parsedDate, "dd/mm/yyyy");
}
```

This is just a snippet but the essentials are in there :-) Hope this might help you! Btw I am using a xlsx-file.

The trick is to pass the option 'cellDates: true' and then to just instantiate a date from the numbers value and it should work out. Your date will probably be a few hours off because of the utc-dates in JS, which you can even out by adding the offset to the date.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I cannot implement it now and verify, since I am not currently working on that project. I am selecting the answer though.

Comment: For me the problem is that output binary data has inverted days with months.

Comment: @KonradGrzyb I have the same problem "Output binary data has inverted days with months". does anyone find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @BrijeshGajera  I've changed library to https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/write-excel-file and https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file.

Answer (score 34):

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
  type: 'binary',
  cellDates: true,
  cellNF: false,
  cellText: false
});
```

Comment: `cellDates: true` converts dates to JS `Date` (not to string as asked). And it has a conversion bug where especially dates before ~1600 are completely off.

Answer (score 19):

```
 const workbook = excel.readFile(file.path);

 const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
 const json = excel.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {
  raw: false,
 });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, could you explain why raw : false worked though?

Comment: This solution is working for me also. In fact, the sheet_to_json method no longer accepts cellDates as an option. Using version: 0.17.2. Thanks @Ashish.

Comment: Sadly this only works for dates 01/01/1900 or later.

Answer (score 2):

```
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(file, {cellDates: true, dateNF:"dd/mm/yy"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, then, I resolve it from here.

Look, I have the value 0.333333333333333 like date. But the user input 8:00:00AM

Excel set the date like sequential numbers from 1/1/1900 then 1 for this.

There I Implements the next seek the timestamp:

```
const excelTimestamp = 0.333333333333333;
const unixTimestamp = (excelTimestamp - 25567) * 86400 * 1000;
const date = new Date(unixTimestamp);
```

And in this moment, is piece of cake!

Regards and I hope help you.

PD. The result is: 1900-01-01T08:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 0):

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
  type: 'binary',
  cellDates: true,
  cellNF: false,
  cellText: false
});

 const options = {
        raw: false, 
        dateNF: 'dd-mm-yyy', // Specify the date format string here
      };
      this.worksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(rawWS, options)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).