# The time is strangely saved JSON files in SheetJS js-xlsx NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, datetime, google-sheets

when i Retrieving All Values from All Sheets from URL of 2PACX- of Web Published Google Spreadsheet using Node.js, The time, which is recorded in hh:mm format in the original issue, is saved to me as 0.375 in the JSON file. (For 09:00 saved 0.375).

How do I convert it to hh:mm format?

Code:

```
    const request = require("request");
const xlsx = require("xlsx");
const fs = require("fs")

const spreadsheetUrl =
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRVSCTxtQhN1LouT_6aCO2rwJKA5gV0Ovl6siKeCZa0p8iD2QxqLG_g0cOA6Q194kIYB5dQvDZNwA0S/pubhtml";

if (
  /https:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/spreadsheets\/d\/e\/2PACX-.+\/pub(html)?/.test(
    spreadsheetUrl
  )
) {
  const temp = spreadsheetUrl.split("/");
  temp.pop();
  const url = temp.join("/") + "/pub?output=xlsx";
  request({ url: url, encoding: null }, (err, res, buf) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    const workbook = xlsx.read(buf, { type: "buffer" });
    const r = Object.entries(workbook.Sheets).map(([k, v]) => ({
      sheetName: k,
      values: xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(v, { header: '' , dateNF: 'string'}),
    }));
    console.log(r);
    
    var t = JSON.stringify(r)
    


    fs.writeFileSync('arr.json', t, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
      }); ;



  });
}
```

Result in JSON file:

```
[{
"sheetName": "Sheet1",
"values": [{
    "מספר שעור": "7015710-01",
    "שם השעור": "מבוא לחישוב",
    "לומדים": 78,
    "יום": "א",
    "משעה": 0.375,
    "עד שעה": 0.5416666666666666,
    "חדר": "52.2.16 אודיטוריום ראאב",
    "שם מורה": "מר עסלי סעיד",
    "zoom link": "",
    "Pass code": 1
}, {
    "מספר שעור": "7015710-04",
    "שם השעור": "מבוא לחישוב",
    "לומדים": 99,
    "יום": "א",
    "משעה": 0.375,
    "עד שעה": 0.5416666666666666,
    "חדר": "53.2.55 אודיטוריום",
    "שם מורה": "פרופ' בן משה בועז",
    "zoom link": "https://ariel-ac-il.zoom.us/j/81869752122?pwd=V0lmWFRRL0R6Tm56QTdRUHNoMWI3QT09",
    "meeting ID": "818 6975 2122"
}, {
    "מספר שעור": "7017610-01",
    "שם השעור": "חשבון אינפיניטסימלי 1",
    "לומדים": 130,
    "יום": "א",
    "משעה": 0.5416666666666666,
    "עד שעה": 0.625,
    "שם מורה": "ד\"ר שוורץ רוברט",
    "zoom link": "https://ariel-ac-il.zoom.us/j/86115883648?pwd=NGRyb3I2ZlhtK1J3bXJKRFljaHlUZz09"
}, {
    "מספר שעור": "7015721-05",
    "שם השעור": "מבוא לחישוב-תרגיל",
    "לומדים": 39,
    "יום": "א",
    "משעה": 0.625,
    "עד שעה": 0.7083333333333334,
    "חדר": "51.4.55 אודיטוריום",
    "שם מורה": "גב' פרבר אנה"
},
```

The spreadsheet I download is written in Hebrew. When in the Jason file the values less than 0 represent the time.

Comment: Please post your example code, and post the output

Comment: [*JSON.stringify*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has a *replacer* parameter that can be used to modify values. Looks like time is represented as decimal days, so multiply by 24 to get hours, then convert the decimal hours to minutes and you have the values to format as HH:mm (e.g. 0.5416666666666666 is 13:00, 0.7083333333333334 is 17:00).

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50823222/11599789) is helpful.